# sapui5 - Two master pages

Tags: javascript, url-routing, master-pages, sapui5

I've got two master pages with dynamic lists.

Master Page 1:

```
<Page title="Title" showBackButton="true" id="master1">
    <List id="idListAuctions" mode="SingleSelectMaster" select="onPressGoToMaster2" items="{auctions>/AuctionsGlobal/0/AuctionsTypes}">
        <items>
            <StandardListItem title="{auctions>AuctionType}" type="Navigation" />
        </items>
    </List>
</Page>
```

Master Page 2:

```
<List id="idListAuctionsDetail" mode="SingleSelectMaster" select="handleListSelect"
            items="{AuctionTypes/Auctions}">
    <items>
        <StandardListItem>
          <!-- Output the items from Master Page 1 -->
        </StandardListItem>
    </items>
</List>
```

My Javascript:

```
onPressGoToMaster2 : function(oEvent) {
    console.log( oEvent.getParameter("listItem").getBindingContext() ); //undefined
    this.byId("hdcSplitApp").toMaster(this.createId("master2"),'slide', oEvent.getParameter("listItem").getBindingContext());
},
```

My JSON File:

```
{
    "AuctionsGlobal": [{
        "AuctionsTypes": [{
            "AuctionType": "Delivery",
            "Auctions": [{
                "AuctionID": "12345"
            }, {
                "AuctionID": "54321"
            }]
        }, {
            "AuctionType": "Contract",
            "Auctions": [{
                "AuctionID": "98745"
            }, {
                "AuctionID": "56478"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

I want to display the items from the selected "Auction" from `master1` on my `master2` page. There seems to be no data on `master2`. I've tried so much but i don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using named model for binding list, model name should be passed to the [`getBindingContext`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.html#getBindingContext) as argument.

Further, use [`setBindingContext`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.html#setBindingContext) to set binding context of list from second master page with context obtained by `getBindingContext`.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/banoyo/edit?html,js,output) is working example.

Comment: Thanks, that's great but i don't know how to use this path :-( 
`this.byId("hdcSplitApp").toMaster(this.createId("master2"),'slide', context);`
How can i use the path on `master2`? Sorry, i'm a newbie in sapui5

Comment: check modified answer!

Comment: Ah, ok. Thank you so much :-)